# Minecraft crashes upon fullscreen

Tags: crash, fullscreen, minecraft

Both pressing F11 and turning on fullscreen in video settings closes the game and reopens the launcher. This happens in both modded and unmodded in all versions. It's apparently is happening outside of java but I'm not completely sure.

Here is the normal and extended crash report:

http://pastebin.com/1DBmg9JZ.

And yes, my video card driver is fully updated.